# How often should I check whether an fstream object is open?

Tags: c++, optimization, file-io, fstream

I use an fstream object to write data to a text file. I write some initial data to it once and then write more data to it in a loop. Every time before writing to the file stream, I check whether it's open. Is this unnecessary? Should I only check once immediately after creating the fstream object?

Basically, I do this:

```
#define STOP 32700 // some value that indicates no more data is available
#include <string>
#include <exception>
#include <fstream>

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
try {
    double data[5] {};
    const std::string output_file_name {"name.txt"}
    std::fstream outputFile (output_file_name, std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc);
    if (outputFile.is_open()) // successfully opened file
        outputFile << "initial text\n";
    else // if text file could not be opened
        throw Fstream_Exception;

    /* do some other stuff (in various threads) */

    do { // ok, now get data and write it to the file!
        getData(&data[0]);
        if (outputFile.is_open())
            outputFile << data[0] << '\n';
        else
            throw Fstream_Exception;
    } while (data[0] != STOP);
}
catch (Fstream_Exception& fstream_exception) {
/* handle exception */
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stream itself can throw exceptions when an error occurs.  Just use its `exceptions()` method and pass the types of errors you want it to detect.  This is more convenient than checking the state flags after each operation.

Comment: I see... so I could do something like `outputFile.exceptions(std::fstream::failbit | std::fstream::badbit);` before my `try` and then use `catch (std::fstream::failure fstream_exc)`? And that would throw an exception if – among other things – the file were somehow deleted or the user didn't have write rights?

Comment: Correct.  You may not even need try/catch, because the program will exit with a failure code and print the exception message all by itself.  You may still want try/catch if you prefer to customize the error handling though.

Comment: I didn't try it without try/catch, but I made the output file write-only and caught an exception with `catch (std::exception& e)`. Your solution is far more elegant than my original design! Thanks for the tip.